# mysql_query in a while loop

Tags: php, database, mysql, loops

I'm trying to execute
I have an html form in a page of this sort :

```
Name: <input type="text" id="namebox" value="" name="fields[]" /> <br />
Position: <input type="text" id="positionbox" value="" name="fields[]" /> <br />

<input type="hidden" name="createcard">     
<input type="submit" value="Create">
```

.. and 3 other fields. I'm passing these 5 form fields by POST to a file process.php which has the following function to insert the array elements into a mysql DB.

```
if(isset($_POST['createcard'])){
    $this->procCreateCardtheme1();
..
..

    function procCreateCardtheme1(){
    global $session;

            $cardData = $_POST['fields'];
            $username=$session->username;
            $sno=1;
            echo count($cardData);
            while($sno < count($cardData))
            {
             $v=$cardData[$sno];
             echo $v;
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO carddata VALUES ('$username', $sno, '$v', 1)");
             $sno++;
            }
```

Now, the echo statement above returns the expected output, that is the five or so fields. But the mysql_query only executes once. It just stores the first entry in the DB, and nothing else. Even re-submitting the form does nothing at all. It's just the one entry that is stored in the DB.
Any ideas?

Comment: not a good idea to execute a query in a loop. form the query in the loop and execute it outside.

Comment: Change to `mysql_query("INSERT INTO carddata VALUES ('$username', $sno, '$v', 1)") or die(mysql_error())` and tell us what the output is. Plus, be sure to escape user input data for safety!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will do so..

Comment: Yes. I will add mysql_real_escape_string() to the user data. :) Thanks ;)

Comment: Also, you do validation on the $username, even as it comes from $session, you never know when some other page screws up and stores a bad user name in the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a unique constraint on `username` in the `carddata` table? This will cause the second insert to fail.

To debug this you should add some error checking to your program:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO carddata VALUES ('$username', $sno, '$v', 1)")
    or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

You might also need to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid syntax errors or possible SQL injection vulnerabilities if the string data can contain quotes.

Comment: I want it to be the same username. I just need the array values to be changing. i.e. $cardData[0], $cardData[1] and so on..

Comment: @Hardik Ruparel: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE carddata` in your question?

Comment: @Hardik Ruparel: You initialize `$sno` with  `1`. I think you should initialize it with `0`.

Comment: @Felix. Yep. I noticed that too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Single Loop iteration issue occurs when you have issue with variable for query ($query)
and Result Object ($result).

Try different name for variable inside the WHILE Loop or debug the variable inside the loop.